# How to make sure a JavaScript code would be executed only once in React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use [file upload with preview](https://github.com/johndatserakis/file-upload-with-preview) and this is the code of my component:

```
const [uploadField, setUploadFiled] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    const temp = new FileUploadWithPreview('fileUpload', {
        multiple: multiple,
    });
    window.addEventListener(Events.IMAGE_ADDED, (e) => {
        const { detail } = e;
        console.log('detail', detail);
    });
}, [])
```

The problem is that since I have `<React.StrictMode>` I see two file upload controls in my page. And whenever I save the file, because of HMR another control would be created.

I want to only run that initialization code once.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Return a cleanup function that destroys the `FileUploadWithPreview`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useRef` hook to store a reference to the `FileUploadWithPreview` instance.

This will ensure that the code is only executed once, even when HMR is enabled.

```
const uploadFieldRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
    const temp = new FileUploadWithPreview('fileUpload', {
        multiple: multiple,
    });

    uploadFieldRef.current = temp;

    window.addEventListener(Events.IMAGE_ADDED, (e) => {
        const { detail } = e;
        console.log('detail', detail);
    }); 
}, []);
```

Comment: Did not work. I still get two instances, and on each save another one is added.

Answer (score 0):

try useRef hook

```
 const effectCalled = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (effectCalled.current) return;
    console.log("app rendered");
    effectCalled.current = true;
  }, []);
```